# I got an error with susbstring management

Tags: java, android

I will create a random number with a 4-digit number and ask the user to enter 4-digit numbers. The user will try to guess.I'm trying to make a game where any number that the user enters matches any number of random numbers generated by the program, which will inform the user and ask the user to delete and re-guess the value that the user enters. For this reason, I tried to break down the number entered with the substring method and check that the numbers match, but the program gave an error. Does anyone know what I did wrong? Here's the code I wrote

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
    public static final Random randomNumberOne = new Random();
    public static final Random randomNumberTwo = new Random();
    public static final Random randomNumberThree = new Random();
    public static final Random randomNumberFour = new Random();
    private TextView msgTvOne, msgTvTwo, msgTvThree, msgTvFour;
    private EditText editText1;
    private EditText editText2;
    private EditText editText3;
    private EditText editText4;
    private Button button_onayla;
    private int NumberToFindOne,NumberToFindTwo,NumberToFindThree,NumberToFindFour, numberTries;
    private String s;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        msgTvOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameTxtViewOne);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button_onayla = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_onayla);
        button_onayla.setOnClickListener(this);

        newGame();
    }

    private void newGame() {
        NumberToFindOne = randomNumberOne.nextInt(10);
        NumberToFindTwo = randomNumberTwo.nextInt(10);
        NumberToFindThree = randomNumberThree.nextInt(10);
        NumberToFindFour = randomNumberFour.nextInt(10);
        msgTvOne.setText(R.string.begining_msg);
        editText1.setText("");
        numberTries = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == button_onayla) {
            button_onayla();
        }
    }

    private void button_onayla() {
        int nOne = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
        numberTries++;
        String subs = Integer.toString(nOne);
        String sOne = subs.substring(1, 2);
        String sTwo = subs.substring(2, 3);
        String sThree = subs.substring(3, 4);
        String sFour = subs.substring(4);

        int iOne = Integer.parseInt(sOne);
        int iTwo = Integer.parseInt(sTwo);
        int iThree = Integer.parseInt(sThree);
        int iFour = Integer.parseInt(sFour);

        if (iOne == NumberToFindOne && iTwo == NumberToFindTwo && iThree == NumberToFindThree && iFour == NumberToFindFour) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tebrikler, tahminin doğru! \n Deneme Sayısı: " + numberTries , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if (iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree && iFour != NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşmedi.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne == NumberToFindOne && iTwo == NumberToFindTwo && iThree == NumberToFindThree || iOne == NumberToFindOne && iTwo == NumberToFindTwo && iFour == NumberToFindFour
                || iTwo == NumberToFindTwo && iThree == NumberToFindThree && iFour == NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi üç sayı eşleşti.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree || iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iFour != NumberToFindFour
                || iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree && iFour != NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşmedi.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne == NumberToFindOne && iTwo == NumberToFindTwo || iOne == NumberToFindOne && iThree == NumberToFindThree
                || iOne == NumberToFindOne && iFour == NumberToFindFour || iTwo == NumberToFindTwo && iThree == NumberToFindThree
                || iTwo == NumberToFindTwo && iFour == NumberToFindFour || iThree == NumberToFindThree && iFour == NumberToFindFour){
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi iki sayı eşleşti.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo || iOne != NumberToFindOne && iThree != NumberToFindThree
                || iOne != NumberToFindOne && iFour != NumberToFindFour || iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree
                || iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iFour != NumberToFindFour || iThree != NumberToFindThree && iFour != NumberToFindFour){
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşmedi.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne == NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree && iFour != NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşti.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo == NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree && iFour != NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşti.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree == NumberToFindThree && iFour != NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşti.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree && iFour == NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşti.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }else if (iOne != NumberToFindOne && iTwo != NumberToFindTwo && iThree != NumberToFindThree && iFour != NumberToFindFour) {
            msgTvOne.setText("Herhangi bir sayı eşleşmedi.");
            editText1.getText().clear();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi George! Please provide the error the program is giving you

Comment: Can you provide errors or logcat messages you encounter?

Comment: Wild guess: is your indexing off by one in the calls to `substring`? The first item is at index 0, not 1. In that case, multiple lines are wrong but the line `subs.substring(4)` will give you an `IndexOutOfRange` because the string only hast 4 characters - i.e. characters at positions 0,1,2,3

Comment: Btw, George, make sure that future questions of yours contain the error you are getting and if possible a *minimal* code sample. That makes it easier for us to answer, and more likely that you find the solution yourself while trying to get rid of everything in your code snippet that is not relevant to the problem you're having. See also [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Is this want you really want (to get the four digits)?

```
        String sOne = subs.substring(0, 1);
        String sTwo = subs.substring(1, 2);
        String sThree = subs.substring(2, 3);
        String sFour = subs.substring(3);
```

Comment: yeah, i'm a new this area. Can u help me

Comment: did you notice the index starts from 0 here? Instead of 1 like in your code.